# Unable to run npm install successfully

Tags: npm

I'm trying to run `npm install` (NPM version 8.13.2) but I'm getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/sipospeter/.npm/_logs/2022-07-07T15_22_06_762Z-debug-0.log
```

I can't figure out what to do, I've updated and logged in to NPM. I've reset my password too.

What do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: is it possible for you to share what's in the 2022-07-07T15_22_06_762Z-debug-0.log file, you should also come that you have RW permission for the folder you are running the npm install also try the npm install -g

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I kind of afraid sharing logs, since its my work computer and I don't think that the company will be happy with an intern sharing logs on the internet.
I'll try npm install -g and the RW permissions, and i'll come back with the results

Comment: Thank you @iamdeed, using npm install -g solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have RW permission for the folder where `npm install` is executed, also try `npm install -g`.